# Spring Boot Actuator /auditevents does not work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-boot-actuator

Actuator /auditevents endpoint

By default /auditevents endpoint is enabled so after starting the application (and logging in with username user and password that is provided in application log) you can see the current security events but when I go to `/auditevents` endpoint I dont see anything:

```
{
    "events": [ ]
}
```

My authentication code:

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;

 AuthenticationManager authenticationManager

Authentication authentication = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        authenticationRequest.getUsername(),
                        authenticationRequest.getPassword()
                )
        );
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

what I get when I try to login:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2017-06-27T08:20:24.344+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "exception": "org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException",
    "message": "Access Denied",
    "path": "/authentication"
}
```

How to logs events to /auditevents?

Comment: Because you are authenticating yourself. The events are fired from the Spring Security filters but as you aren't using those for authentication the events never occur.

Comment: How to fire Spring Security filters manually?

Comment: You shouldn't. Why do you need your own authentication mechanism? Why are you trying to bypass the Spring Security ones?

Comment: It was already clear you are using Spring Security. But for authentication you are bypassing spring security... Why?

Comment: I have similar code to this:
https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo

Comment: Use a filter that extends the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and implement the necessary method to integrate with the normal flow of Spring Security.